# JSON Monolith Model, how it relates to State and constructing the Store?

Tags: ngrx, ngxs

I have a project where I get a large up front JSON which is essentially becomes the state to the program. A silly example of the JSON may look like this:

```
{
   app: {
     people: [
        {
            name: "bill",
            dob: "04/05/2017",
        }
     ]
   }
}
```

So this is my data. But it isn't my state which may look something like this with default initialization.

```
   app: {
     people: []
   }
```

And I actually want it to be this

```
   app: {
     people: [
        {
            name: "bill",
            dob: "04/05/2017",
            daysOld: 365
        }
     ]
   }
```

The key thing I do not understand about either `ngrx`/`ngxs` is the relationship between my Model and my State. A lightbulb which fails to fire.

1. What mechanism is responsible for creating a collection of people?
2. What mechanism is responsible for calculating the age of each person

Or I am off piste entirely? Is trying to generate an entire store in advance from a monolith just the wrong approach? For example does my Model go somewhere and I use this as a reference to dynamically later create state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been learning ngxs for the past week of two.

This is what i understand.

Q: What mechanism is responsible for creating a collection of people?

A: [`@Action()` decorated functions](https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/concepts/state#simple-actions) in your `@State()` decorated class should be responsible for manipulating your application's state AND operations with [side effects](https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/concepts/state#async-actions) (i.e. async work like HTTP GET/POST).

So both creating person object by manipulating your app's state and persisting person object on server is handled within `@Action`  decorated functions.

---

Q: What mechanism is responsible for calculating the age of each person

A: You can select a slice of your application state, dob of a person in this case, and calculate the age, then return the value (as "derived" state value). This can be done in [`@Select()`](https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/concepts/select) decorated functions.

---

Q: Is trying to generate an entire store in advance from a monolith just the wrong approach?

A: I don't know. I think depends on nature of your application. I imagine we cannot possibly load entire app's data into state (memory) all the time - unless the app's state is very small.

---

Q: For example does my Model go somewhere and I use this as a reference to dynamically later create state?

A: I imagine this is the case most of the time. So, in `@State()` decorated class, we will inject some kind of `HttpPersonLoaderService` where you call at some point to load/save remotely.

---

Lastly, just want to share a simple [ngxs example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngxs-books-selector?file=state%2FBookState.ts) with you. This simple example does not load data remotely though.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am going to spend tonight mulling this over and I appreciate the time you took to write it given the nebulous question.

Comment: @kctang nice example, thanks! Do you know how the `thickBooks` stream/selector is updated (magically)? It the filter applied with each change of the books collection?